# MongoDB: Find documents but drop duplicates by key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What I want is to find documents but drop duplicates by key and retrieve only the updated document (by a date field).

So for this collection:

```
{
    "key": "a", 
    "time": ISODate("2021-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "key": "a",
    "time": ISODate("2020-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "key": "b",
    "time": ISODate("2020-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "key": "b",
    "time": ISODate("2019-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

We will get the following docs:

```
{
    "key": "a",
    "time": ISODate("2021-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "key": "b",
    "time": ISODate("2020-10-20T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$sort` - Order the documents by `key` ASC and `time` DESC.
2. `$group` - Group by `key` and take the first document as `data`.
3. `$replaceWith` - Decorate output document with `data`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "key": 1,
      "time": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      "data": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$data"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Qq3n6t3gVe)